# chrome devtools networking issue

Tags: performance, google-chrome-devtools

there is like 80ms after DOM loaded, and before CSS / JS starts loading and I have no idea whats going on.
I would happily share you my .HAR file, but no idea where to attach files.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Please use Timeline. It will show what happens with the page at that time.